# How to add a column which has auto increment value based on update of other column in a list

Tags: custom-list, calculated-column

I have a list where in we are capturing Completion Month date. It can be updated by users if required. I need to have a record of number of times this value is updated for each individual row starting from default value of 0.

Can I create a calculated column based on above requirement.

Answer (score 0):

- Add a number Column '*Completion changed*' (don't need a Calculated Column)
- Add a text column '*previous Completion Date*'
- **Create a SharePoint Designer Workflow**
  Set to trigger on Item changes

Workflow steps:

- read value from *previous Completion Date*
- read value from *Completion Date*
- if values are equal then do nothing
- if values **not** equal then
- read value from *Completion changed*
- increment value
- write value to *Completion changed*